# Is there anyway to figure out what STL header file has not been included directly?

Tags: c++, stl

Our product uses C++ as the programming language. One annoying issue of using C++ STL is that we forget to include the necessary header files, because the file may have been included in some other STL header, the build passes. For example,

In Mac platform using Xcode, if I use `std::auto_ptr` without include `memory.h` but include `iostream.h`, the build will pass, but it will fail in Android platform.

But I don't want move the code to Android for an build check for each code change commit. So, is there anyway to avoid that problem?

Edit 1:
I know the best solution is to not forget the include the header. But developers make mistakes. So is there any tool to help check it?

Edit 2:
Seams no ideal solution, so I will use vim script to check it in my editor,the solution is similar to https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-cpp-auto-include/blob/master/ftplugin/cpp_auto_include.vim

Comment: It's a weakness of C++ (and C), it's a wider problem than just the STL, any large project with complex header file dependencies has this problem.. There's no solution that I'm aware of, you just have to be careful.

Comment: The best way is that when you use a standard library feature (and remember that [the STL is not the same as the C++ standard library](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StlIsNotTheCppStandardLibrary)), is to always remember to include the header file that defines that feature. If want to use e.g. smart pointers, then always include `<memory>`.

Comment: The only think i can advice is to always include the needed `.h` file, even if you know that it already gets included implicitly. For example, if you use `std::auto_ptr`, then `#include <memory>` even if you know that `instream` includes it implicitly.

Comment: Also note that you should **not** include C++ standard header files that end in `.h` unless you're on a very **very** old version of a compiler/library. The C++ standard library header files haven't used `.h` since before the C++98 standard.

Comment: You may put up your include files in a special file (perhaps call it CommonHeaders.h) which includes the classes/libraries that you will require all across your project and just include that single file every time you add a new file into your project.

Comment: @AbhiP, will this make the build very slow, because of include unnecessary one?

Comment: If you are not careful about what you are including, then yes. If the common header starts looking like it has 100 lines, then you are into serious trouble. But if there are STL classes, for example set, that are used across all the files, then it is a good idea. It is also great if there are some common macros that you may want access to.

Comment: @ZijingWu: Such common headers can often be pre-compiled, which makes it a one-time cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only tool I know of... is the compiler itself.

Whenever the issue is portability, the best solution I have seen was to simply put on automated build/test suites for all required environments. Then, whenever a pull request is made it will be validated on all your build bots, and you will be warned if you forgot something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `common_includes.h` file that includes all necessary files there, and include that file everywhere you need. This will simplify the situation and will help out forgetting to include some file. At least you will forget it only one time :).